# Clean up Context file in React typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a file where I create a context and I was wondering if there is a way to make this look nicer?

```
type ToolsContextType = {
    updateSelected: (newSet: Set<string>) => void,
    selected: Set<string>
}

export const ToolsContext = createContext({
    updateSelected: (newSet: Set<string>) => {},
    selected: new Set<string>()
});

export const ToolsProvider = ({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) => {
    
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState(new Set<string>());
    const updateSelected = (newSet: Set<string>) => {
        setSelected(newSet);
    }
    
    return (
        <ToolsContext.Provider value={{
            updateSelected,
            selected
        }}>
            {children}
        </ToolsContext.Provider>
    )
}
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

I tried thinking of ways to make the code cleaner but I can't do that without making things more complex

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
type ToolsContextType = [
  Set<string>,
  React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<Set<string>>>
];

const ToolsContext = createContext<ToolsContextType>(null as any);

export const ToolsProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children }) => {
  const selectedState = useState(new Set<string>());
  return (
    <ToolsContext.Provider value={selectedState}>
      {children}
    </ToolsContext.Provider>
  );
};

export const useToolsContext = () => useContext(ToolsContext);
```

Usage:

```
const [selected, setSelected] = useToolsContext();
```

I prefer to just initialize the context with `null as any` because it's less clutter, and it will throw an immediate error if you forget to provide the context where required. I've never seen a situation where the default value is useful.

I know it's ugly and clunky, the context API is a big drawback of React in my opinion.